# Method pow does not exist error Pyspark error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, strong-typing

This is a bit strange.

When I create a dataframe and then do some transformations with the function pow, it works. But when I push it to run in a real world scenario, it does not. The datatype of columns in my dummy and the real world scenario is the same

Error

```
Method pow([class java.lang.Double, class java.lang.Double]) does not exist
```

This works (with made up data)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType

columns = ["CounterpartID","Year","Month","Day","churnprobability", "deadprobability"]
data = [(1234, 2021,5,12, 0.85,0.6),(1224, 2022,6,12, 0.75,0.6),(1345, 2022,5,13, 0.8,0.2),(234, 2021,7,12, 0.9,0.8), (1654, 2021,7,12, 1.40,20.0), (7548, 2021,7,12, -1.40,20.0),  (6582, 2021,7,12, -1.40,20.0)]



schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("CounterpartID",IntegerType(),False), \
    StructField("Year",IntegerType(),False), \
    StructField("Month",IntegerType(),False), \
    StructField("Day", IntegerType(), False), \
    StructField("churnprobability", DoubleType(), False), \
    StructField("deadprobability", DoubleType(), False) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

abc=df.withColumn("client_id", f.col("CounterpartID"))\
      .withColumn("year", f.col("Year"))\
      .withColumn("month", f.col("Month"))\
      .withColumn("day", f.col("Day"))\
      .withColumn("churn_probability_unit", f.col("churnprobability").cast(IntegerType()))\
      .withColumn("churn_probability_nanos", ((f.col("churnprobability") - f.col("churnprobability").cast(IntegerType())) * pow(10,9)).cast(IntegerType()))\
      .withColumn("dead_probability_unit", f.col("deadprobability").cast(IntegerType()))\
      .withColumn("dead_probability_nanos", (f.col("deadprobability") %1 * pow(10,9)).cast(IntegerType()))\
      .select("client_id", "year", "month", "day", "churn_probability_unit", "churn_probability_nanos", "dead_probability_unit","dead_probability_nanos")\

abc.show()
```

However, instead of df, in the real world scenario (Production job), I have a real dataframe ( of course) and all columns in that has the same datatype as my dummy dataframe above:

e.g. here:

[image: Production Dataframe]

However, when I do the same transformation, it complains of not able to find the pow function with double parameters. Here's the stack trace (below). I have also looked up the docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#pow), for pow, but it does not talk anything about datatypes. Some S.O posts suggests Double should be ok. where is it going wrong? I can of course change it multiply by the actual number , instead of using pow, but I would still like to understand this better. Any questions, and I can help answer.

```
----> 7       .withColumn("churn_probability_nanos", ((f.col("churnprobability") % 1.0) * pow(10,9)).cast(IntegerType()))\
      8       .withColumn("dead_probability_unit", f.col("deadprobability").cast(IntegerType()))\
      9       .withColumn("dead_probability_nanos", (f.col("deadprobability") %1 * pow(10,9)).cast(IntegerType()))\

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in pow(col1, col2)
    737     Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument.
    738     """
--> 739     return _invoke_binary_math_function("pow", col1, col2)
    740 
    741 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in _invoke_binary_math_function(name, col1, col2)
     73     and wraps the result with :class:`~pyspark.sql.Column`.
     74     """
---> 75     return _invoke_function(
     76         name,
     77         # For legacy reasons, the arguments here can be implicitly converted into floats,

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in _invoke_function(name, *args)
     57     """
     58     jf = _get_get_jvm_function(name, SparkContext._active_spark_context)
---> 59     return Column(jf(*args))
     60 
     61 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    108     def deco(*a, **kw):
    109         try:
--> 110             return f(*a, **kw)
    111         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    112             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
--> 330                 raise Py4JError(
    331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.pow. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method pow([class java.lang.Double, class java.lang.Double]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:341)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:362)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:289)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: i see that in your example code, you did not import the pyspark sql `pow()`, so it is possible it used python's built-in `pow()`. Could it be that you imported `pow()` from `pyspark.sql.functions` in your real world scenario? the two functions are a bit different when it comes to its inputs.

Comment: I think that is the problem. somehow, it seems in my dummy example, the native python pow was used, whereas in the real world scenario the pyspark pow. Not sure why, because the setup was exactly the same. The only difference I could see is the cluster runtime (spark and scala version) - dummy had : 11.1.x-scala2.12 and the real world: 8.2.x-scala2.12. These are databricks cluster runtime versions. Maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: there must be an import statement importing the pyspark sql `pow()` in your real world scenario -- look for `from pyspark.sql.functions import pow` which overrode the python's built-in `pow()` function

Comment: Exactly, that was the problem , somewhere out on the top in the real world scenario, which I didn't have in my dummy scenario. Now, it is absolute concrete , why it behaved differently in the 2 scenarios. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in (py)Spark are developped in Scala, and therefore, are strongly typed.
It means that the signature of the function is part of the function. For example :

```py
def foo(bar:str):
   ...

# AND

def foo(bar:int):
   ...
```

These two functions are the same in python. They are different functions in Scala because the input type is different.

In your case, pyspark `pow` with input as double does not exists. But, `pow` that accepts `columns` as input exists.
It probably works in your first example because you are not using the pyspark `pow` but, instead, the built-in python `pow`.

I'd advice you to always use `F.function_name`. Many python functions and pyspark functions have the same name so Python will overwrite its built-in functions with the imports.

You should simply change your code to :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

F.pow(F.lit(10), F.lit(9))
```

NB: [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit) creates a column using the input param.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But do you know why then the same code works for my made up dataframe ? there I used  pow(10,9) and it worked.

Comment: @SaugatMukherjee because `pow` is a built-in python function. Do you know which `pow` you are using each time ? either the [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) from python or the [`pow`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pow) from pyspark ?

Comment: Same comment as I made to samkart: I think that is the problem. somehow, it seems in my dummy example, the native python pow was used, whereas in the real world scenario the pyspark pow. Not sure why, because the setup was exactly the same. The only difference I could see is the cluster runtime (spark and scala version) - dummy had : 11.1.x-scala2.12 and the real world: 8.2.x-scala2.12. These are databricks cluster runtime versions. Maybe that makes a difference